# Android Studio release signed apk :app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease java.io.IOException

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, release, sign

I just updated to Android Studio 2.1.1 and I am trying to build a release signed apk but failed with the error below. How can I solve this ?

```
':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
    > java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

this is the build.gradle (module: app)

full version: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/65bb2edf94ea58c50de8e0ff107555ce

```
...
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.company.project"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 13
        versionName "1.5"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
}
```

more on the error Message dump
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9d822c530011b48dab1da60267f9b471

UPDATE:

content of proguard-rules.pro
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9d822c530011b48dab1da60267f9b471

content of /Users/xxxx/Library/Android/sdk/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d5cdfbfd7c1bfe74d594993feb35bd62

content of /Users/xxxx/Library/Android/sdk/tools/proguard/proguard-project.txt
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d04cd0299029d4fdd648fb782f2e3021

Comment: You need to config your proguard property as you have enabled it. Please post proguard property. From your error it has problem due to retrofit, please add proguard property of retrofit.

Comment: it looks quite empty, im not familiar with proguard. here is the content https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9d822c530011b48dab1da60267f9b471

Comment: i'ved included sdk proguard-android.txt and proguard-project.txt

Comment: Check out [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) to add proguard rules.

Comment: still same error. i included retrofit rules in the sdk  sdk proguard-android.txt - https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d0736683ad5cc0cb5939c9bf3463dbfd

Comment: How many libraries you have added? I think you may need for every third party library, I see facebook and aws call from your error log! please check respective sdk's proguard rules

Comment: man, really. is there a way to make life easier on this ? this is my build.gradle

Comment: i dont think it will go that straight with proguard! either disable proguard until you learn how to use it properly(if it is emergency for your app to launch) or take it step by step.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113017/discussion-between-axil-and-shvet).

Answer (score 0):

As you havent added proguard rules in your `proguard-android.txt` file i would suggest you to add all necessary rules to make release apk from your project.

For `retrofit` you need to add below rules:

```
-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions
```

You also need to add other rules too like,

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class com.google.android.gms.internal.*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgent
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment

-keep class com.google.android.gms.maps.** { *; }
-keep interface com.google.android.gms.maps.** { *; }

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static *** CREATOR;
}
# The Maps API uses serialization.
-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}
```

This is common for most of projects and i have used for my project, Please check whole rule before using it.